# How to write urdu text in PDF using iText 7?

Tags: pdf, itext7, urdu

I am creating a PDF report with custom font "Jameel Noori Nastaleeq.ttf".

The pdf is showing Urdu alphabets instead of Urdu words like if I type "تنویر" the pdf report shows it as alphates "ر ى و ن ت".

Please guide me how to set RTL setting in iText 7.

Comment: writing systems that require ligatures need pdfCalligraph for iText 7 and iText 8.